# Como alterar o conteudo "código" de uma section com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Oi, preciso alterar o conteúdo (código) de uma section com javascript com a função .click ou onClick mas o conteúdo não pode sobre por o da outra section! Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi bem o que quer, acho que é isto:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-sect1');
var sect1 = document.getElementById('sect1');
btn = btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sect1.innerHTML = '<h1>Agora já não é o original</h1><p>Está aqui outro codigo html</p>'
});
```

```html
<section id="sect1">
  <h1>Aqui está o codigo original da sect1</h1>
</section>
<section id="sect2">
  <h1>Aqui está o codigo original da sect2</h1>
</section>
<button id="btn-sect1">Mudar HTML da sect1</button>
```

Comment: No caso poderia adicionar mais de uma tag!

Comment: @user50404 Mais de uma tag? Como assim, mais de uma tag HTML dentro da section onde queremos alterar o HTML?